# Evaluate function returning "undefined" value

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

The following piece of code is returning the value in one browser (IE 11) but in the browser(IE 11) which is in a different server, it is throwing an error "checkRatingId is undefined".

```
<cfloop index="FieldName" list="#fieldNames#">
    <cfset field_name = #FieldName#>
    <cfset firstThreeChars = #Mid(field_name,1,3)#>

        <cfif firstThreeChars eq "CQI">
        <cfset checkQuestionId = #RemoveChars(field_name,1,3)#>

        <cfset checkRatingId = #Evaluate("#field_name#")#>

        <cfquery name="InsQuestions" datasource="#variables.dbdsn#" username="#variables.dbuser#" password="#variables.dbpw#">
            insert into quality.employee_quality_call_detail
            (quality_call_detail_id, check_question_id, check_rating_id, quality_call_id,
             last_user, last_update)
            values
            (quality.seq_emp_quality_call_detail.nextval, '#checkQuestionId#','#checkRatingId#',
             '#qualityCallId#', '#currentHRID#',sysdate) 
        </cfquery>

    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Do not use evaluate. It can pose a security risk. Instead use the FORM structure and associative array notation to access form fields dynamically.  Regarding the question, can you please provide a complete repro case? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]).

Comment: Are you sure both servers are running the same version of coldfusion #SERVER.ColdFusion.ProductVersion#